# Counting unique domain names from a column

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a google apps script which fetches the G Suite (google apps) users from the [AdminDirectory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list)

As on output, i get the domain name in front of every user (used replace to extract domain name from each user email id).

what i want to do-:
1. Count the number of users on each domain in one column, so end result should look like this-:

Column - I (exaxple)
domainA.com = 120 users
domainB.com = 28 users
etc....

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is probably a way to shorten this code, but something like this will work. You will have to figure out how to read the correct columns in and output to the correct columns, but hopefully, this will help out:

```
var emails = [
  'someone@testA.com',
  'someone@testB.com',
  'someone@testA.com',
  'someoneelse@testA.com'
];

function countDomains() {
  var domainCounts = {};

  var domains = emails.map(function(domain) {return domain.split('@')[1];});

  domains.forEach(function(each) {
    if(domainCounts.hasOwnProperty(each)) {
      domainCounts[each]++;
    } else {
      domainCounts[each] = 1;
    }
  });

  Logger.log(domainCounts);
}
```